# Convert .zsh_history file to .bash_history file

Tags: bash, zsh

Recently I decided to move from zsh to bash shell. Is there a way to quickly convert my `.zsh_history` file to `.bash_history` file?

`.zsh_history` snippet

```
: 1446994188:0;cat .bash_profile
: 1446994197:0;echo $shell
: 1446995957:0;vi ~/.zshrc
: 1437893246:0;curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \\
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

`.bash_history` snippet

```
#1446994188
cat .bash_profile
#1446994197
echo $shell
#1446995957
vi ~/.zshrc
#1437893246
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Please note that command can span multiple lines.

Comment: Sounds like it could be possible - it'd be helpful if you included a sample of the input and the desired output. Have you tried anything, perhaps using sed or awk?

Comment: yes, tried them, but couldn't get it working easily. They have very different formats with regards to timestamp, separaters etc. Looking here, if someone has done this before and has something handy.

Comment: @sdayal as Tom suggest it would make it easier for us to help you if you include a .zsh_history snippet and an expected .bash_history result

Comment: Thanks Tom and and @dev-null. I've added snippets

Comment: It would make things slightly easier if the input and output matched up :)

Comment: Also, an example of a multi-line history entry from your `.zsh_history` would be very useful, as the trivial case is easy enough to handle; but those of us who do not have easy access to Zsh cannot guess what those look like.  For what it's worth, Bash forces multi-line commands to a single line in the history.

Comment: Experimentation on a Mac OSX Yosemite with Zsh reveals that multiple-line history entries have a backslash before the newline to continue them on the next line. (I was unable to figure out how to get the timestamps in there. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111718/command-history-in-zsh helped figure out that I need to set `SAVEHIST` as well as `HISTFILE` to enable this functionality.)

Comment: thanks @triplee updated i/o formats and also added multiline example

Comment: So now the question is, what does a bare backslash look like in `zsh_history`?  I assume that `\\ ` is a line break which (unlike on my machine) got merged to a single line ...? Which doesn't make sense really, but if you say so.

Answer (score 4):

It's strange, I don't have those commented lines in my .bash_history, anyway, I would use something like this

```
sed 's/^: \([0-9]*\):\w;\(.*\)$/#\1\n\2/' <.zsh_history >.bash_history
```

I'm far from being an expert in regexps, so that might be done better, but I'll explain what it does.

```
 sed 's/^ -- start of the line
      :   -- tell the regexp there's a ":"
      \([0-9]*\) -- identify a series of numbers and store that in 1
      :\w; -- another ":" followed by a word and by ";" 
      \(.*\)$ -- store whatever you find until the end of the line in 2
      /#\1\n\2/' -- print what you have in 1 on a line and what you have in 2 on the next
```

Comment: Looks good and nice explanation but worth mentioning that this relies on a version of sed that understands `\w` (e.g. GNU sed). Using `-r` would save you having to escape the capture groups.

Comment: Uh thanks for that Tom, I didn't know about that flag.

Comment: Something more needs to be done here to handle multi-lines.

Comment: I tested this and it worked with your sample, could you expand on what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

This awk script appears to do the right thing:

```
awk -F'[:;] *' '{printf "#%s\n%s\n", $2, $4}' file
```

The field separator is defined as either a semicolon or colon followed by any number of spaces. The two fields of interest are then printed, along with the `#` and newlines.

Testing it out on your input:

```
$ cat file
: 1446994188:0;cat .bash_profile
: 1446994197:0;echo $shell
: 1446995957:0;vi ~/.zshrc
$ awk -F'[:;] *' '{printf "#%s\n%s\n", $2, $4}' file
#1446994188
cat .bash_profile
#1446994197
echo $shell
#1446995957
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Something more needs to be done here to handle multi-lines. Also, this is not able to handle lines of type `: 1444493409:0;git clone https://github.com/xyz/abc.git`

Comment: My answer worked with your original input - I see that it has changed now but there are still no multi line entries. If your requirements are more complex then you should edit the input / output in your question.

Answer (score 3):

On macOS I was able to use the following. It correctly handles commands with colons but I'm not sure about multi-line commands.

```
awk -F'[:;] *' '{ st = index($0,";");printf "#%s\n%s\n", $2, substr($0,st+1)}' ~/.zsh_history > ~/.bash_history
```

Answer (score -1):

for those using MacOSX Catalina I was able to resolve it by creating a symlink from *`.zsh_history`* file to *`.bash_history`* file.

Simple remove **.bash_history** then:

**sudo ln -sf .zsh_history .bash_history**

Its working perfect for me.

Comment: bash history and zsh history are completely incompatible, they must be converted.